# Fragment inside a fragment android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I am working with Fragments.

See the image below.[image]

can we hold different activity's(Activity A) fragment(Fragmet A1) inside a fragment(Fragment B2) of another activity(Activity B)?

Is it possible how can we do this ?

Answer (score 4):

```
public void addInnerFrag() {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragContainer, new InnerFrag()).commit();
        getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Use getChildFragmentManager when adding Fragments inside of a Fragment.

Comment: @hitch.united I am getting the error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from MusicAlbumFragment to Fragment". public class MusicAlbumFragment extends Fragment . The extending Fragment is (android.app.Fragment).

Comment: Use fragment of one type only ..either android.app.Fragment or appsupport fragment

Comment: @hitch.united FYI... I have changed to android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Now I am getting ClassCastException. java.lang.ClassCastException: packageName1.MyHomeActivity cannot be cast to packageName2.MusicHome

Comment: FYI... I have changed to android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Now I am getting ClassCastException. java.lang.ClassCastException: packageName1.MyHomeActivity cannot be cast to packageName2.MusicHomeActivity at the line of private MusicHome musicHomeListener;

 @Override
 public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onAttach(activity);
  
  musicHomeListener = (MusicHome)activity;
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible we can place fragment inside another fragment.

the solution is while you adding the fragment you will use `getFragmentManager()`.
while adding the child fragment inside the fragment you have to use `getChildFragmentManager()`;

the following link may useful to you: [here](http://rootzwiki.com/topic/36433-nested-fragments-example-for-android-42-api-v17/)